# Have Jest Spec Sleep after Button Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, axios, enzyme

I have a react component and when the submit button is clicked it fires off two API calls, both of which I want to be able to test.

I've mocked axios like so

```
jest.mock('axios', () => jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({})));

axios.mockImplementation((request) => {
  console.error(request);
  switch (request.url) {
    case '/api-1':
      return Promise.resolve(api1Mock);
    case '/api-2':
      return Promise.resolve(api2Mock);
    default:
      return Promise.reject(new Error('not found'));
  }
});
```

when I run my spec I check to see if it has been called twice, and the spec returns it was only called once and then errors.

```
      expect(axios).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
```

However I'm able to see both console logs for both API calls so i know they're both being hit. Any ideas?

Comment: hi your code looks good but what about the request.url may not match the value od swich case

Comment: Please provide the code you want to test.